# Summations Inequality:

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I have a problem with some sumations, it seems to be a trivial problem but I haven't been able to solve it. Please, any help will be awesome.
Thanks!

Let $a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i$ real sequences of n elements such that:
$\forall i$ 
$$a_i>b_i$$
$$1\geq c_i>d_i> 0$$
and

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i c_i >0$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n b_i d_i >0$$
Then, prove that
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i c_i >\sum_{i=0}^n b_i d_i $$
Comments:
It seems quite friendly, but I have issues when there are negative values for $a_i,b_i$

Comment: So, the difficulty lies in cases where $a_i$ may be negative?

Comment: Yes, it can't be for all the values, but if it is negative for some values it can be messy

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true.  Consider the case where $n=2$.

\begin{align}
a&=(-1,4)\\
b&=(-2,3.9)\\
c&=(.5,.5)\\
d&=(.03125,.45)
\end{align}
These numbers obey the given pairwise inequalities.

Then 
$$
a_1c_1+a_2c_2=-.5+2=1.5
$$
and
$$
b_1d_1+b_2d_2=-.0625+1.755=1.6925.
$$

Comment: You are right... so the original problem I had in mind was the following:
Let $h_i, h_j, f_i,f_j$ continuous functions such that $f$ are increasing and $f(0)=0$,  Assume that:
$\forall x$ 
$$h_i (x)>h_j (x)$$
$$f_i (x)>f_j (x)$$
and

$$\int_{0}^\infty h_i (x) f_i (x)dx>0$$
$$\int_{0}^\infty h_j (x) f_j (x)dx>0$$
Then, prove that
$$\int_{0}^\infty h_i (x) f_i (x)dx>\int_{0}^\infty h_j (x) f_j (x) dx$$

I thought that by discretizing it, it will be easier to prove... but given your counterexample, im not sure how to extend it...

Comment: @Nick: you didn't discretize correctly. There are $2m$ functions, hence there should be $2mn$ discrete values, not $4n$.

Comment: mmm... you are right... silly mistake of my side... sorry :( I think I will post the main question explicitly again.... 
Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: If you are interested, I just post it under the title "Inequality with Products of Integrals". Thanks for the help and sorry for my fail try and the time you loss...@YvesDaoust, @Michael_Burr

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false,

$$-1>-2$$ but $$-1\cdot1\ngtr-2\cdot\frac13.$$

And adding other terms to obtain positive sums,

$$10\cdot1-1\cdot1\ngtr9.999\cdot0.999-2\cdot\frac13.$$

Comment: @MichaelBurr: ooops, I missed these conditions, but you are right the fix easy.